# .NET Resize Event: Get old size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've added a resize event to one of my widgets, which looks like this:

```
void glControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
```

Is there a way I can get the old size of the widget (before resizing)? Maybe I can cast `e` to something that will give me more info? Or should I just save it during that event?

Comment: If you want an event **before** resize is actually done by Windows override `WndProc` and catch the right message. I'm not sure which exactly. But it's the only way to get a **before resize**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, just tracking the old size in a class field is the simple solution.  For example:

```
Size mOldSize;

private void glControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (mOldSize != Size.Empty && mOldSize != glControl.Size) {
    // do something...
  }
  mOldSize = glControl.Size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By convention you should add an `OnResizing` event, which fires just when it is about to change but hasn't changed, and then you fire the `OnResize` after it has been resized. You would get the old value from your `EventArg` in the `OnResizing` event.

Edit:

Are you creating your own event or firing one of an included control?

If you are doing your own event, you can derive from `EventArg` and make something like `ResizeEventArg` that include the size of the thing you want.

I would use the `ResizeEventArg` for both the `Resize` and `OnResizing` events, and still follow what I said earlier.

Or if you know which type of control it is, you could cast the `Object sender` into the type and then read the property.

Comment: I'm not creating my own event. And it doesn't have an `OnResizing` event? Nothing seems to have an `OnResizing` event? I see a `ResizeBegin` on my main form, but this is a `Tao.Platform.Windows.SimpleOpenGlControl` which doesn't seem to have either. Guess I'm snookered. Thanks anyway. Good for future reference.